# Email notifications for inbox messages?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, email

Is there any way to have magento send me an email when I get a message in my admin inbox?  I don't log in often and would like to stay on top of of security patches, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct way to do this. However, the messages come from a RSS feed: http://notifications.magentocommerce.com/community/notifications.rss

You can use a service like [IFTT](https://ifttt.com/) to send updates to yourself via mail

Comment: Ok, I logged in to Magento today and saw there was a new notification (update to 1.9.2.0 including more critical security patches).  I checked IFTTT to see why I didn't receive an email, and the recipe I set up is getting the following errors: "Feed Trigger Error" and "Trigger Timeout Error."  It looks like IFTTT is not happy with the Magento RSS feed because it doesn't validate (see https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fnotifications.magentocommerce.com%2Fcommunity%2Fnotifications.rss).

Any ideas on how we can get that working?

Comment: I'm afraid not, since it's a remote source (magento itself) it's impossible to change the feed itself

Comment: Guess I'll just get an RSS plugin for chrome and monitor it myself - thanks for your feedback

Comment: Thank you for specifying the URL - had to find it out to allow it in my firewall as exception.

Comment: PS Has anybody an idea how to update the inbox? How to force magento to fetch the notifications?